# Ionic 3 Highcharts not visible

Tags: highcharts, ionic3, angular2-highcharts

I have the following flow in my application:

`firstpage` --> `secondpage` (contains highchart) --> `thirdpage` --> `fourthpage` --> `secondpage`

When I go from `firstpage` to `secondpage`, the chart is visible. Also when I go back from `thirdpage` to `secondpage`, I can see the chart. But when I go from `fourthpage` to `secondpage`. Th chart is not there anymore. The data of the chart is static, it does not have any dependencies:

```
...
import * as HighCharts from 'highcharts';

@Component({
   ...
})
export class SecondPage {
  ...

  constructor(...) {
   ...
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad SecondPage');
      this.myChart = HighCharts.chart('container', {
        chart: {
          type: 'line'
        },
        title: {
          text: 'Finanzplan 5 Jahre Mietdauer'
        },
        xAxis: {
          categories: ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5' ]
        },
        yAxis: {
          title: {
            text: 'Euro'
          }
        },
        series: [
          {
            name: 'Jane',
            data: [1, 0, 4]
          },
          {
            name: 'John',
            data: [5, 7, 3]
          }
        ]
      });
  }

}
```

The call from `firstoage` and `fourthpage` are identical:

`this.navCtrl.push(SecondPage);`

For the call from `firstpage` to `secondpage` I get:

```
<div id="highcharts-8183bcq-0" dir="ltr" class="highcharts-container " style="position: relative; overflow: hidden; width: 23px; height: 400px; text-align: left; line-height: normal; z-index: 0; -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);"><svg version="1.1" class="highcharts-root" style="font-family:&quot;Lucida Grande&quot;, &quot;Lucida Sans Unicode&quot;, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:12px;" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="23" height="400" viewBox="0 0 23 400"><desc>Created with Highcharts 6.0.4</desc><defs><clipPath id="highcharts-8183bcq-1"><rect x="0" y="0" width="0" height="224" fill="none"></rect></clipPath><clipPath id="highcharts-8183bcq-2"><rect x="-99" y="-89" width="99" height="400" fill="none"></rect></clipPath><clipPath id="highcharts-8183bcq-3"><rect x="0" y="0" width="0" height="224" fill="none"></rect></clipPath></defs><rect fill="#ffffff" class="highcharts-background" x="0" y="0" width="23" height="400" rx="0" ry="0"></rect><rect fill="none" class="highcharts-plot-background" x="66" y="89" width="0" height="224"></rect><g class="highcharts-grid highcharts-xaxis-grid "><path fill="none" class="highcharts-grid-line" d="M 65.5 89 L 65.5 313" opacity="1"></path></g><g class="highcharts-grid highcharts-yaxis-grid "><path fill="none" stroke="#e6e6e6" stroke-width="1" class="highcharts-grid-line" d="M 65.5 313.5 L 65.5 313.5" opacity="1"></path><path fill="none" stroke="#e6e6e6" stroke-width="1" class="highcharts-grid-line" d="M 65.5 238.5 L 65.5 238.5" opacity="1"></path><path fill="none" stroke="#e6e6e6" stroke-width="1" class="highcharts-grid-line" d="M 65.5 164.5 L 65.5 164.5" opacity="1"></path><path fill="none" stroke="#e6e6e6" stroke-width="1" class="highcharts-grid-line" d="M 66.5 88.5 L 66.5 88.5" opacity="1"></path></g><rect fill="none" class="highcharts-plot-border" x="66" y="89" width="0" height="224"></rect><g class="highcharts-axis highcharts-xaxis "><path fill="none" class="highcharts-tick" stroke="#ccd6eb" stroke-width="1" d="M 66.5 313 L 66.5 323" opacity="1"></path><path fill="none" class="highcharts-axis-line" stroke="#ccd6eb" stroke-width="1" d="M 65.5 313.5 L 65.5 313.5"></path></g><g class="highcharts-axis highcharts-yaxis "><text x="23.609375" text-anchor="middle" transform="translate(0,0) rotate(270 23.609375 201)" class="highcharts-axis-title" style="color:#666666;fill:#666666;" y="201"><tspan>Euro</tspan></text><path fill="none" class="highcharts-axis-line" d="M 66 89 L 66 313"></path></g><g class="highcharts-series-group"><g class="highcharts-series highcharts-series-0 highcharts-line-series highcharts-color-0 " transform="translate(66,89) scale(1 1)" clip-path="url(#highcharts-8183bcq-3)"><path fill="none" d="M 0 194.13333333333333 L 0 224 L 0 104.53333333333333" class="highcharts-graph" stroke="#7cb5ec" stroke-width="2" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-linecap="round"></path><path fill="none" d="M -10 194.13333333333333 L 0 194.13333333333333 L 0 224 L 0 104.53333333333333 L 10 104.53333333333333" stroke-linejoin="round" visibility="visible" stroke="rgba(192,192,192,0.0001)" stroke-width="22" class="highcharts-tracker"></path></g><g class="highcharts-markers highcharts-series-0 highcharts-line-series highcharts-color-0 highcharts-tracker" transform="translate(66,89) scale(1 1)" clip-path="url(#highcharts-8183bcq-2)"></g><g class="highcharts-series highcharts-series-1 highcharts-line-series highcharts-color-1 " transform="translate(66,89) scale(1 1)" clip-path="url(#highcharts-8183bcq-3)"><path fill="none" d="M 0 74.66666666666666 L 0 14.933333333333337 L 0 134.4" class="highcharts-graph" stroke="#434348" stroke-width="2" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-linecap="round"></path><path fill="none" d="M -10 74.66666666666666 L 0 74.66666666666666 L 0 14.933333333333337 L 0 134.4 L 10 134.4" stroke-linejoin="round" visibility="visible" stroke="rgba(192,192,192,0.0001)" stroke-width="22" class="highcharts-tracker"></path></g><g class="highcharts-markers highcharts-series-1 highcharts-line-series highcharts-color-1 highcharts-tracker" transform="translate(66,89) scale(1 1)" clip-path="url(#highcharts-8183bcq-2)"></g></g><text x="12" text-anchor="middle" class="highcharts-title" style="color:#333333;font-size:18px;fill:#333333;" y="24"><tspan>Finanzplan</tspan><tspan dy="21" x="12">5 Jahre</tspan><tspan dy="21" x="12">Mietdauer</tspan><title>Finanzplan 5 Jahre Mietdauer</title></text><text x="12" text-anchor="middle" class="highcharts-subtitle" style="color:#666666;fill:#666666;" y="88"></text><g class="highcharts-legend" transform="translate(-13,346)"><rect fill="none" class="highcharts-legend-box" rx="0" ry="0" x="0" y="0" width="49" height="39" visibility="visible"></rect><g><g><g class="highcharts-legend-item highcharts-line-series highcharts-color-0 highcharts-series-0" transform="translate(8,3)"><path fill="none" d="M 0 11 L 16 11" class="highcharts-graph" stroke="#7cb5ec" stroke-width="2"></path><path fill="#7cb5ec" d="M 12 11 A 4 4 0 1 1 11.999998000000167 10.996000000666664 Z" class="highcharts-point"></path><text x="21" style="color:#333333;font-size:12px;font-weight:bold;cursor:pointer;fill:#333333;" text-anchor="start" y="15"><tspan></tspan><title>Jane</title></text></g><g class="highcharts-legend-item highcharts-line-series highcharts-color-1 highcharts-series-1" transform="translate(8,17)"><path fill="none" d="M 0 11 L 16 11" class="highcharts-graph" stroke="#434348" stroke-width="2"></path><path fill="#434348" d="M 8 7 L 12 11 8 15 4 11 Z" class="highcharts-point"></path><text x="21" y="15" style="color:#333333;font-size:12px;font-weight:bold;cursor:pointer;fill:#333333;" text-anchor="start"><tspan></tspan><title>John</title></text></g></g></g></g><g class="highcharts-axis-labels highcharts-xaxis-labels "><text x="66" style="color:#666666;cursor:default;font-size:11px;fill:#666666;" text-anchor="middle" transform="translate(0,0)" y="332" opacity="1">1</text></g><g class="highcharts-axis-labels highcharts-yaxis-labels "><text x="51" style="color:#666666;cursor:default;font-size:11px;fill:#666666;" text-anchor="end" transform="translate(0,0)" y="318" opacity="1"><tspan>0</tspan></text><text x="51" style="color:#666666;cursor:default;font-size:11px;fill:#666666;" text-anchor="end" transform="translate(0,0)" y="243" opacity="1"><tspan>2.5</tspan></text><text x="51" style="color:#666666;cursor:default;font-size:11px;fill:#666666;" text-anchor="end" transform="translate(0,0)" y="168" opacity="1"><tspan>5</tspan></text><text x="51" style="color:#666666;cursor:default;font-size:11px;fill:#666666;" text-anchor="end" transform="translate(0,0)" y="94" opacity="1"><tspan>7.5</tspan></text></g><text x="13" class="highcharts-credits" text-anchor="end" style="cursor:pointer;color:#999999;font-size:9px;fill:#999999;" y="395">Highcharts.com</text></svg></div>
```

And for the second time (`fourthpage` --> `secondpage`) which is when it does not work, I get:

```
<div id="highcharts-8183bcq-4" style="position: relative; overflow: hidden; width: 23px; height: 400px; text-align: left; line-height: normal; z-index: 0; -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);" dir="ltr" class="highcharts-container "><svg version="1.1" class="highcharts-root" style="font-family:&quot;Lucida Grande&quot;, &quot;Lucida Sans Unicode&quot;, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:12px;" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="23" height="400" viewBox="0 0 23 400"><desc>Created with Highcharts 6.0.4</desc><defs><clipPath id="highcharts-8183bcq-5"><rect x="0" y="0" width="0" height="224" fill="none"></rect></clipPath></defs><rect fill="#ffffff" class="highcharts-background" x="0" y="0" width="23" height="400" rx="0" ry="0"></rect><rect fill="none" class="highcharts-plot-background" x="66" y="89" width="0" height="224"></rect><g class="highcharts-grid highcharts-xaxis-grid "><path fill="none" class="highcharts-grid-line" d="M 65.5 89 L 65.5 313" opacity="1"></path></g><g class="highcharts-grid highcharts-yaxis-grid "><path fill="none" stroke="#e6e6e6" stroke-width="1" class="highcharts-grid-line" d="M 65.5 313.5 L 65.5 313.5" opacity="1"></path><path fill="none" stroke="#e6e6e6" stroke-width="1" class="highcharts-grid-line" d="M 65.5 238.5 L 65.5 238.5" opacity="1"></path><path fill="none" stroke="#e6e6e6" stroke-width="1" class="highcharts-grid-line" d="M 65.5 164.5 L 65.5 164.5" opacity="1"></path><path fill="none" stroke="#e6e6e6" stroke-width="1" class="highcharts-grid-line" d="M 66.5 88.5 L 66.5 88.5" opacity="1"></path></g><rect fill="none" class="highcharts-plot-border" x="66" y="89" width="0" height="224"></rect><g class="highcharts-axis highcharts-xaxis "><path fill="none" class="highcharts-tick" stroke="#ccd6eb" stroke-width="1" d="M 66.5 313 L 66.5 323" opacity="1"></path><path fill="none" class="highcharts-axis-line" stroke="#ccd6eb" stroke-width="1" d="M 65.5 313.5 L 65.5 313.5"></path></g><g class="highcharts-axis highcharts-yaxis "><text x="23.609375" text-anchor="middle" transform="translate(0,0) rotate(270 23.609375 201)" class="highcharts-axis-title" style="color:#666666;fill:#666666;" y="201"><tspan>Euro</tspan></text><path fill="none" class="highcharts-axis-line" d="M 66 89 L 66 313"></path></g><g class="highcharts-series-group"><g class="highcharts-series highcharts-series-0 highcharts-line-series highcharts-color-0 " transform="translate(66,89) scale(1 1)" clip-path="url(#highcharts-8183bcq-5)"><path fill="none" d="M 0 194.13333333333333 L 0 224 L 0 104.53333333333333" class="highcharts-graph" stroke="#7cb5ec" stroke-width="2" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-linecap="round"></path><path fill="none" d="M -10 194.13333333333333 L 0 194.13333333333333 L 0 224 L 0 104.53333333333333 L 10 104.53333333333333" stroke-linejoin="round" visibility="visible" stroke="rgba(192,192,192,0.0001)" stroke-width="22" class="highcharts-tracker"></path></g><g class="highcharts-markers highcharts-series-0 highcharts-line-series highcharts-color-0 highcharts-tracker" transform="translate(66,89) scale(1 1)"></g><g class="highcharts-series highcharts-series-1 highcharts-line-series highcharts-color-1 " transform="translate(66,89) scale(1 1)" clip-path="url(#highcharts-8183bcq-5)"><path fill="none" d="M 0 74.66666666666666 L 0 14.933333333333337 L 0 134.4" class="highcharts-graph" stroke="#434348" stroke-width="2" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-linecap="round"></path><path fill="none" d="M -10 74.66666666666666 L 0 74.66666666666666 L 0 14.933333333333337 L 0 134.4 L 10 134.4" stroke-linejoin="round" visibility="visible" stroke="rgba(192,192,192,0.0001)" stroke-width="22" class="highcharts-tracker"></path></g><g class="highcharts-markers highcharts-series-1 highcharts-line-series highcharts-color-1 highcharts-tracker" transform="translate(66,89) scale(1 1)"></g></g><text x="12" text-anchor="middle" class="highcharts-title" style="color:#333333;font-size:18px;fill:#333333;" y="24"><tspan>Finanzplan</tspan><tspan dy="21" x="12">5 Jahre</tspan><tspan dy="21" x="12">Mietdauer</tspan><title>Finanzplan 5 Jahre Mietdauer</title></text><text x="12" text-anchor="middle" class="highcharts-subtitle" style="color:#666666;fill:#666666;" y="88"></text><g class="highcharts-legend" transform="translate(-13,346)"><rect fill="none" class="highcharts-legend-box" rx="0" ry="0" x="0" y="0" width="49" height="39" visibility="visible"></rect><g><g><g class="highcharts-legend-item highcharts-line-series highcharts-color-0 highcharts-series-0" transform="translate(8,3)"><path fill="none" d="M 0 11 L 16 11" class="highcharts-graph" stroke="#7cb5ec" stroke-width="2"></path><path fill="#7cb5ec" d="M 12 11 A 4 4 0 1 1 11.999998000000167 10.996000000666664 Z" class="highcharts-point"></path><text x="21" style="color:#333333;font-size:12px;font-weight:bold;cursor:pointer;fill:#333333;" text-anchor="start" y="15"><tspan></tspan><title>Jane</title></text></g><g class="highcharts-legend-item highcharts-line-series highcharts-color-1 highcharts-series-1" transform="translate(8,17)"><path fill="none" d="M 0 11 L 16 11" class="highcharts-graph" stroke="#434348" stroke-width="2"></path><path fill="#434348" d="M 8 7 L 12 11 8 15 4 11 Z" class="highcharts-point"></path><text x="21" y="15" style="color:#333333;font-size:12px;font-weight:bold;cursor:pointer;fill:#333333;" text-anchor="start"><tspan></tspan><title>John</title></text></g></g></g></g><g class="highcharts-axis-labels highcharts-xaxis-labels "><text x="66" style="color:#666666;cursor:default;font-size:11px;fill:#666666;" text-anchor="middle" transform="translate(0,0)" y="332" opacity="1">1</text></g><g class="highcharts-axis-labels highcharts-yaxis-labels "><text x="51" style="color:#666666;cursor:default;font-size:11px;fill:#666666;" text-anchor="end" transform="translate(0,0)" y="318" opacity="1"><tspan>0</tspan></text><text x="51" style="color:#666666;cursor:default;font-size:11px;fill:#666666;" text-anchor="end" transform="translate(0,0)" y="243" opacity="1"><tspan>2.5</tspan></text><text x="51" style="color:#666666;cursor:default;font-size:11px;fill:#666666;" text-anchor="end" transform="translate(0,0)" y="168" opacity="1"><tspan>5</tspan></text><text x="51" style="color:#666666;cursor:default;font-size:11px;fill:#666666;" text-anchor="end" transform="translate(0,0)" y="94" opacity="1"><tspan>7.5</tspan></text></g><text x="13" class="highcharts-credits" text-anchor="end" style="cursor:pointer;color:#999999;font-size:9px;fill:#999999;" y="395">Highcharts.com</text></svg></div>
```

Comment: Does your `console.log` fire when you go from `fourthpage` to `secondpage`?

Comment: yes it does. i have also debugged it. it enters the function

Comment: It's strange.. maybe element is hidden or has width/height set as 0px? Could you try rendering chart in `setTimeout()` just to check this?

Comment: how can I do that?. I have just seen that when I come from secondpage,
 its: <div id="container" style="display: block;" data-highcharts-chart="0"><div id="highcharts-q7nein0-4" style="position: relative; overflow: hidden; width: 337px; height: 400px; text-align: left;...>...</div></div> 
and when I come from fourthpage, its just: <div id="container" style="display: block;"></div>

Comment: It's strange.. it looks like chart is not created at all. Could you add: `chart: { events: { load: function () { console.log(this.container) } } }` and let me know if container is set?

Comment: Where exactly should I add this?

Comment: In the [chart config](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.load).

Comment: I have added the output in the question above...

Comment: So the chart is there, small one (`width: 23px; height: 400px;`) but exists.  I'm not sure if I can help you further without live demo. Are you able to setup one?

Comment: @farham...try moving you code to <code>ionViewDidEnter()</code> instead of <code>ionViewDidLoad()</code>.

Comment: @PrerakTiwari its still the same problem. The first time the chart is there, but the second time its not there anymore

Comment: @PawełFus but why then is the chart HTML code not visible in the source code of the page? Its just.. `<div id="container" style="display: block;"></div>`

Comment: That suggest something removed the chart, I don't see any other option.

Comment: @PawełFus I have just seen, that the browser does not show the highcharts HTML part in the "developer tools" during the second call, but when I get the source-code of the `container` `div` by doing right click and copy element. I then also see highcharts HTML part in the source code after the second call

Comment: And if you replace Highcharts chart code with some static element added by `appendChild` ? Does it show up correctly? Could you also some other versions (6.0.0, 6.0.1, ... ) ? Here you can find upcoming 6.0.5 version: http://github.highcharts.com/highcharts.src.js

Comment: I checked the source code that I have after the second call in more detail. Something strange is happening. Where the source code , that I get after the first call is almost ending. The source code, that I get after the second call continues as if its again creating the whole page: `</div></ion-content>
257. </page-overview><page-currentlyused class="ion-page show-page" style="z-index: 103;" hidden="">
258. <ion-header class="header header-md">` Then the code of the whole page is repeated and this time the `div container` is empty. So the first `div container` in the same source code ...

Comment: does contain the highchart part, but the the second `div container` is empty. and this happens in the one source code file that I get after the second call

Comment: So this means, the chart is only filled in the first `div container` and the second `div container` stays empty. but that is the container that is actually shown on the page ...

Comment: @PawełFus: I solved the issue with the double `div container`s by removing `secondPage` from the call stack after arriving at `thirdPage` with: `this.navCtrl.remove(this.navCtrl.last().index);` Now it works... :)

Comment: wow, that is strange, congrats! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue with the double `div containers` by removing `secondPage` from the call stack after arriving at `thirdPage` with:

`this.navCtrl.remove(this.navCtrl.last().index);`

Now it works... :)